# i am using getElement but it's not working in my code, why?

Tags: javascript

I trying to change the color of a "p" tag using getElementById(), but its not working...

HTML:

```
<p id="fon">changing color</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
    var c = document.getElementById(fon);
    c.style.color = 'blue';
```

Comment: i just learning out JavaScript

Comment: Typo. SHould be `document.getElementById('fon')`

Comment: `document.getElementById(fon);` should be `document.getElementById("fon");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id should be in quotation marks

```
document.getElementById("fon");
```

Comment: Thanks, my phone doesn't have the correct quotation marks. Didn't notice that.

Comment: worked, but if i use getElementByClassName, don't work too:

Comment: var d = document.getElementByTagName('p');
 d.style.color = 'red';

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: getElementByTagName() returns a collection rather than the element itself. You can read more of it from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp). getElementByClassName() works the same as getElementByTagName in the way that it returns an HTMLcollection as seen [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp).

Comment: I get it! Thank you ErikkM!! you help me so much!!

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to change paragraph color using JS. You can use this code .. :)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title></title>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function changecolor()
            {
            document.getElementById("fon").style.color='blue';
            }
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <p id="fon" onclick="changecolor()"> hello this is a para</p>
            </body>
            </html>
```